# Ansible check if variable exists in attribute list

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have a variable containing details of host machines on my network (called 'hostlist' - I believe you call this a dictionary, but I'm not sure of the terminology. The variable is defined in a file in group_vars/all, so it's available in all playbooks (not sure if this is important).

I have a play which I would like to run only if ansible_hostname is not found in the list of host names in hostlist. The host names in hostlist are one of the attributes of the variable, but again I'm not sure if "attribute" is the right term...

Hostlist is defined as:

```
hostlist:
  - { name: 'host1', ip_addr: '192.168.2.31', hostgrp: 'physical_workstation' }
  - { name: 'host2', ip_addr: '192.168.2.32', hostgrp: 'physical_workstation' }
  - { name: 'host3', ip_addr: '192.168.2.33', hostgrp: 'virtual_machine' }
```

The play I'm using to try to get this working is:

```
- name: Conditional test
  debug:
    msg: "ansible_hostname not found in hostlist."
  when: ansible_hostname not in hostlist.name
```

I'm not sure of the syntax required in the condition, or if what I'm wanting is achieveable in this manner?

Comment: This would be a lot easier if your "hostlist" was actually part of your inventory. Why isn't it?

Comment: I tried doing that earlier on, but I am wanting to be able to run my playbook on new machines where there is no ansible hosts file present (I use a template doc to deploy an /etc/ansible/hosts file based on hostlist contents)

Comment: It sounds like you should just be creating an inventory file instead of this "hostlist".

Comment: Potentially - I'll look into this also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are presumably more elegant ways of doing it, but something like this works for me:

If your inventory file looks like this

```
host1
host2
host3
host4
```

Then a playbook with the following content, would only be run against `host4` because it isn't matched in the hostlist var:
`$ cat test.yml`

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    hostlist:
      - { name: 'host1', ip_addr: '192.168.2.31', hostgrp: 'physical_workstation' }
      - { name: 'host2', ip_addr: '192.168.2.32', hostgrp: 'physical_workstation' }
      - { name: 'host3', ip_addr: '192.168.2.33', hostgrp: 'virtual_machine' }
  tasks:

    - name: Conditional test
      debug:
        msg: "ansible_hostname not found in hostlist."
      when: hostlist|selectattr("name", "equalto", ansible_hostname)|list|length == 0
```

when called like this:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml
```

means that only host4 runs the block of tasks....

```
PLAY [all] *************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************
ok: [host1]
ok: [host2]
ok: [host3]
ok: [host4]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************
ok: [host4] => {
    "msg": "hostname not in hostlist name list"
}
skipping: [host1]
skipping: [host2]
skipping: [host3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This looks like it's what I'm after, but when I try to create your example playbook and run as per your command, I get:

[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: host3
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: host4
ERROR! Specified hosts and/or --limit does not match any hosts


...Not sure how I can get the same output?

Comment: so you can remove the `-l host3:host4`, that was just so that it didn't run against every other host in my inventory. let me update with the full inventory example...

Answer (score 2):

Optionally, this condition is cleaner

```yaml
    when: inventory_hostname not in hostlist|map(attribute="name")|list
```

---

Use `inventory_hostname` instead of `ansible_hostname` if you want to compare to the list of inventory's aliases. See [What's the difference between inventory_hostname and ansible_hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908067/whats-the-difference-between-inventory-hostname-and-ansible-hostname#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20access,used%20in%20the%20inventory%20file.).

Answer (score 0):

an alternative solution is (as suggested in the comment on the question) is to refactor the hostlist into the inventory like so:

```
[physical_workstation]
host1 ansible_host=192.168.2.31
host2 ansible_host=192.168.2.32

[virtual_machine]
host3 ansible_host=192.168.2.33

[all]
host4 ansible_host=192.168.2.34
```

Then you can simplify the playbook to run plays against hosts that are in no groups, using the special `ungrouped` group, which selects hosts from `all` that are not in any other group:

```
- hosts: ungrouped
  tasks:
    - name: only ungrouped
      debug:
        msg: "host not found in any other group."
```

or run things against those specific hosts in groups...

```
- hosts: physical_workstation:virtual_machine
  tasks:
    - name: only in specified groups
      debug:
        msg: |
          This will run on machines that are in groups:
          physical_workstation or virtual_machine
```

outputs

```
PLAY [ungrouped] ***********************************************

TASK [only ungrouped] ******************************************
ok: [host4] => {
    "msg": "host not found in any other group."
}

PLAY [physical_workstation:virtual_machine] ********************

TASK [only in specified groups] ********************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "This will run on machines that are in groups:\nphysical_workstation or virtual_machine"
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": "This will run on machines that are in groups:\nphysical_workstation or virtual_machine"
}
ok: [host3] => {
    "msg": "This will run on machines that are in groups:\nphysical_workstation or virtual_machine"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this also. The key thing for me is that I'm wanting to use my playbook when running ansible-pull on new machines which aren't in the known hosts list, and I'm wanting to do a single line ansible-pull command without needing to first deploy a hosts file with the current machine ip included. I think I had trouble testing your earlier answer because I tried it without adding the test hosts to the hosts file on my test machine. I've tried your "when" condition in my actual playbook and it works exactly as I was wanting. So I'll accept your first answer. Thanks again!